# ESP OTA from Github

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I want to be able to program my ESP32 (same for ESP8266) remotely, I have used ArduinoOTA without problems, and I can upload the file into the ESP selecting the local file that I want to flash.

However I want something different. I want that the ESP downloads the new firmware located in my github repository.

Arduino OTA is just a small webserver that uploads the file from my computer to the ESP and then flashes it.

Is there a library where I can specify a web address and then it downloads the file from there?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already used ArduinoOTA the answer is actually right under your nose!

[OTA update as download](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA#ota-update-as-download)

> OTA update as download
>
> The WiFi101OTA and ArduinoOTA libraries were created for upload from
> IDE. But in some scenarios as for example deployed sleeping battery
> powered devices it is better to have the update available for **download**
> by the device.
>
> In advanced section of examples you can find examples of sketch update
> over **download** from a http server. One example shows update over the
> InternalStorage object of the ArduinoOTA library. The example for
> update over SD card doesn't use this library at all.

[OTASketchDownload examples ArduinoHttpClient include fixed](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/tree/master/examples/Advanced)

There are 2, one mentioning SD cards, the other not:

[OTASketchDownload.ino](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/examples/Advanced/OTASketchDownload/OTASketchDownload.ino)

> This example downloads sketch update over network.  It doesn't start
> the OTA upload sever of the ArduinoOTA library,  it only uses the
> InternalStorage object of the library  to store and apply the
> downloaded binary file

Comment: Checked that. GitHub doesn't work with HTTP but needs HTTPS, so I managed to make a program to reflash the ESP when a newer version is commited to GitHub.

Comment: So you got it working? Well done ;-) would you like to share your program?

Comment: Please share how you accomplished this.